# Stop running a chain of functions in Python if an exception is triggered in one of the earlier functions

Tags: python, function, break

I have a set of functions which, are being called one after another depending on user input. I'm using this code to run the functions:

```
      #Run Multiple Functions
      def MultipleFunctions(*funcs):
          def MultipleFunctions(*args, **kwargs):
              for f in funcs:
              f(*args, **kwargs)
      return MultipleFunctions
```

I am calling the functions with command lines tied to tkinter objects. For instance:

```
      Op1 = OptionMenu(MainForm, Type, *Options, command=MultipleFunctions(Func1, Func2, Func3, Func4))
```

Func1 to 4 run various simple checks mostly to catch illegal option selections. For example Func1 checks the input of an edit box:

```
      #Check SideA Box Length is Valid
      def Func1(event):
          try:
             float(SideA.get())
          except ValueError:
              messagebox.showerror(message="This box only accepts numbers between 0 and 100")
              SideA.focus()
          if float(SideA.get()) > 100:
              messagebox.showerror(message="This box only accepts numbers between 0 and 100")
              SideA.focus()
```

What I want to do is break out of the Multiple Functions routine if an exception is triggered in say Func1. At the moment it runs all four functions regardless.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Thank you

Comment: What about a `try-except` around the  `f(*args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 0):

You code is handling exception in except block.

There are few ways on how to stop execution if exception pops up.

1. You can not handle exception and it'll interrupt program just by itself.
2. You can rethrow exception after handling it in 'except' block.
3. You can return a bool value as a success indicator from your function and add code to either continue or stop your loop in MultipleFunctions based on return value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `try-except` around the function call **and** add a break statement to quit the loop.

Notice: in the decorator don't use the same function's name

```
def MultipleFunctions(*funcs):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            try:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break # <- quit the loop
    return wrapper

def a(): print('a()')
def b(): print('b()')
def c(): print('c()')

# here without exceptions
MultipleFunctions(a, b, c)()
#a()
#b()
#c()

# here with exception: none of the function accept arguments!
MultipleFunctions(a, b, c)(2)
#a() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

---

Further you need to reimplement the body of the function to **raise** exceptions:

```
def Func1(x): # similar to the Func1!
    if isinstance(x, float) or isinstance(x, int):
        if x > 100:
            raise Exception('Error, >100!')
        print('good')
    else:
        raise Exception('Error, not a number')

# to make it compatible with my example they need to be modify like this
def a(*args): print('a()')
def b(*args): print('b()')
def c(*args): print('c()')


MultipleFunctions(a, b, Func1, c)(1113)
#a()
#b()
#Error, >100!

MultipleFunctions(a, b, Func1, c)('smt')
#a()
#b()
#Error, not a number

MultipleFunctions(a, b, Func1, c)(10)
#a()
#b()
#good
#c()
```

---

EDIT From the comments: this is how `Func1` should look like (I have no experience with tkinter)

```
def Func1(event): 
    x = SideA.get()
    
    if isinstance(x, float) or isinstance(x, int):
        if x > 100:
            SideA.focus()
            messagebox.showerror(message="This box only accepts numbers between 0 and 100")
            raise Exception('Error, >100!')
        print('good')
    else:
        SideA.focus()
        messagebox.showerror(message="This box only accepts numbers between 0 and 100")
        raise Exception('Error, not a number')
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the example and pointing out the duplicate function name. I've changed that now. The above example works well in isolation, but when I plug it into my code it permanently fires the "xError, not a number".  When I delved deeper it's because it is reading "x" as "<FocusOut event>" where as I need it to be readying SideA.get(). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Douglas you don't have to copy-paste my `Func1` because doesn't work on your real program, I simply did an abstraction. Use `x = SideA.get()` and pass the event as in your program

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting back to me. I had tried something very similar to your edit, but it was still firing "Error, not a number". When I saw your reply I overwrote my version with your edit code. Same thing. If I print SideA.get() it shows 10. Very strange. I guess that's a different problem though.

Comment: @Douglas but if 10 **as** a string than make sense it is not a number. Please, mention what kind of data `SideA.get()` should return. If it returns a string and you want to check if it is a number you could use `if x.isnumeric():` instead of `if isinstance...:`